# AutoClicker C++ Windows Form

Tags: c++, windows-forms, click

Estoy creando un autoclicker con c++ windows form pero al poner este codigo me sale error

```
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    bool status = false;
    while (true)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F8)) {
            status = true;
        }
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F9)) {
            status = false;
        }
        if (status == true) {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

ese codigo es de un boton que al darle click activa un codigo que al dar f8 hace autoclick y al tocar f9 desactiva el autoclick pero me da error

Answer (score 1):

La función `GetAsyncKeyState` te devuelve,  según la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate), dos cosas:

- si la tecla está pulsada o no
- el momento en el que la tecla se ha pulsado desde la última llamada a `GetAsyncKeyState`

Es decir, esta función no es simplemente un booleano que te dice si una tecla está pulsada o no.

Tu estás evaluando la salida de la función como booleana. Si pulsas la tecla en algún momento, la API va a registrar ese momento y te lo va a devolver a llamar a `GetAsyncKeyState` aunque la tecla no esté pulsada en ese momento.

Ai solo te interesa saber si está pulsada en el momento de la consulta deberías filtrar la salida, quedándote únicamente con el bit de menor peso:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F8) & 0x01)
```

También es posible que debas añadir un pequeño delay entre las dos llamadas a `mouse_event`.

Comment: No me referia a ese error el problema es que me sale un error que dice std::array

Comment: @gordi111 No crees que seria una buena idea incluir el error en ese caso? Sobre todo viendo que no hay un `std::array` claro en el codigo que enviaste3